# How to generate evenly-spaced config voltages from standard DIP switches using only passive resistors?

Tags: analog, switches, resistor-ladder

I am designing a circuit involving an [LTC4316](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4316fa.pdf), which is configured by providing one of sixteen analog voltages on each of the XORH and XORL pins to set the upper and lower nibbles of its configuration byte (which for the specific chip, is the I2C address translation mask).

Ordinarily, for a device with a single fixed I2C address, I would follow the procedure laid out in the datasheet to arrive at appropriate resistor values for a resistor divider. However, for this device, this needs to be settable by the user or installer. My prototype involved using a potentiometer and providing test points for the user to probe to set the voltage, but this is not a very user-friendly procedure; it would be much better to provide a set of discrete DIP switches and some passive resistors.

The datasheet provides the following table for what voltage ratio the configuration pin needs to be placed at for the different configuration values:

```
| addr | ratio Vin/Vcc  |
| ---- | -------------- |
| 0000 | ≤ 0.03125      |
| 0001 | 0.09375 ±0.015 |
| 0010 | 0.15625 ±0.015 |
| 0011 | 0.21875 ±0.015 |
| 0100 | 0.28125 ±0.015 |
| 0101 | 0.34375 ±0.015 |
| 0110 | 0.40625 ±0.015 |
| 0111 | 0.46875 ±0.015 |
| 1000 | 0.53125 ±0.015 |
| 1001 | 0.59375 ±0.015 |
| 1010 | 0.65625 ±0.015 |
| 1011 | 0.71875 ±0.015 |
| 1100 | 0.78125 ±0.015 |
| 1101 | 0.84375 ±0.015 |
| 1110 | 0.90625 ±0.015 |
| 1111 | ≥ 0.96875      |
```

(Note that these are not volts, they're unitless multiples of the input supply voltage.)

Essentially, this is just splitting the range between 0.0 to 1.0 into 16 equal intervals, with the 0.015 tolerance allowing you to hit anywhere in the middle 48% of each interval.

The input impedance of the pins here is really very high -- the datasheet's table also includes recommendations for resistances in a fixed divider, and for e.g. 0111 it recommends using an 887k / 1M.

Note that the voltage levels I need to achieve are not ones I am able to specify myself. There is no programmable uC, and there are no additional voltage supplies other than Vcc and ground.

Technically, I *don't* need the dip switch positions to map neatly to separate bits. The board already has a silkscreened table of DIP switch positions vs the translated addresses of the on-board devices, and this table can be shuffled into any order if there's a clever scheme that can produce these voltages in some order other than the usual one.

An R-2R ladder would be able to achieve a compatible set of evenly-spaced voltages, but the classic design requires inputs driven both to the high and low voltages -- meaning more expensive dual-throw DIP switches rather than the common single-throw type.
Given the high input impedance, using low-value pullups and high-value ladder resistance values could work, but irritatingly the voltages an R2R ladder produces are off by half a step, going from one rail to one step shy of the other rather than something from the middle 48% of each step.

An arrangement that makes use of only a small number of distinct resistor values would be nice, but resistors are cheap -- and as long as I can make do with only basic values, having them assembled is cheap too.

How can I achieve this type of analog voltage configuration in a way that's settable from a DIP switch, using only passive resistance values?

Comment: Is adding a quad buffer / inverter out of the question? This would allow SPST switches and R2R DAC.

Comment: @Transistor it's not totally out of the question, and I suppose that'd probably be cheaper than using SPDT switches. Though, come to think of it it's probably even possible with just some low value pullups and high value R2R resistors -- since that the input impedance here is really quite high (the table I excerpted the voltages from also recommends a 1000k / 887k divider when programming 0111).

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Python or MATLAB. Are you constrained to E24 resistors? How many can you afford (space-wise)?

Comment: @winny I believe I'll need 1% tolerance resistors to achieve the 0.015 voltage tolerances anyway, so theoretically any E96 value should be available -- but on the flip side, it'd be really nice if it could be done using only the 1% resistors on JLC's "Basic Parts" list, to limit setup costs for smaller assembly runs.

Comment: I have an elegant-looking plan, but it involves 8 SPST DIP switches per nibble, which is as many as an R2R ladder would use, as many resistors as well, so no great inclination to post it as an answer. Would the extra space for 8 SPST DIPs outweigh the extra cost of 4 SPDT switches?

Comment: Yes, E96 if you follow the rules. In practice, 1 % E24 are on the market. Have you tried to compute how many you need for a passive solution as benchmark for all the other suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

CircuitLab / Imgur isn't working at the moment so here's an ASCII circuit.

```
           |
          (i) 16.6 uA
           |
    +------+--------> ADDR.
    |      |          0 - 1 V
   \ SW1   \
    \      / 1k
    |      \
    |      |
    +------+
    |      |
   \ SW2   \
    \      / 2k
    |      \
    |      |
    +------+
    |      |
   \ SW3   \
    \      / 4k
    |      \
    |      |
    +------+
    |      |
   \ SW4   \
    \      / 8k
    |      \
    |      |
    +------+- GND
```

By using a constant current source most of the complexity of the resistor divider can be eliminated - with the minor complexity of requiring a top-side constant current source.

The resistor chain can be made of 1, 2, 4 and 8 × 1k resistors which would keep the bill of materials simple at the expense of a few resistors and some PCB real-estate.

Comment: Arguably the CCS is desirable, as a VREF was not mentioned, or whether it can/should be ratiometric with the supply; in this case, an IREF is used instead.  Which makes sense as resistors relate current to voltage; and conversely, a parallel-series circuit switching VREF into a bunch of resistors at zero load voltage would also do (series-parallel transformation, IREF <--> VREF, output having zero current <--> output having zero voltage). Of course the latter takes a transresistance amp to get back to an output voltage, so this is probably better.

Comment: Given that LT shows a minimum resistance value of 100K, this might be a problem for the CCS design.

Comment: @AnalogKid, yes, I'm not familiar with the chip.

Comment: @TimWilliams it does indeed need to be ratiometric -- the datasheet specifies the configuration voltages in terms of that ratio (Vx / Vcc), with the chip using its same supply as VREF.

Comment: @AnalogKid, I had another look through the datasheet and can't find the 100k minimum specification. I can't think why there would be one when it's a voltage reading input.

Comment: @AJMansfield, if Vcc is regulated would the ratio requirement still be an issue? You'd set the current to suit.

Comment: @Transistor The regulator I currently have in the design is ±2%, so I'd need to specify one with a bit tighter tolerance to get within the LTC's 1.5% requirement -- but that wouldn't be too many additional cents.

Comment: How straightforward is it to implement a constant current source for this type of application?

Comment: How much headroom have you got? XORL max is 1.0 V. What's Vcc? [LM134](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm134.pdf?ts=1706546549534)?

Comment: @Transistor that's not a correct reading of that table; those aren't volts, they're unitless constants you multiply by the supply voltage to get the target input voltage. And that supply voltage can be anything from 2.25 to 5.5 volts -- though I'm using it at 3.3 volts in my application.

Comment: OK. Hopefully it gives you some ideas / options.

Comment: @AJMansfield do you have a regulated supply *above* 3.3V (say 5V) that could be used for the extra headroom?

Comment: Gave you an upvote and posted an answer expanding on your idea a bit. Let me know if that's a problem and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @GodJihyo, thank you. No problem. I was interested in the puzzle aspect of the problem.

Comment: Transistor - on page 9 of the datasheet, 0% of the "recommended" resistor values are below 100K.  I put "Recommended" in quotes because in my experience, that word is implicitly in ALL CAPS.  This was explained to me by the Analog Devices applications support manager in a seminar.

Comment: @AnalogKid, but some of them have "Short" which is << 100k! I'd say they're minimising power consumption in the divider. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @SimonFitch I do have a higher unregulated supply of around 5-ish volts, so if there's a clean solution that would just need a second low-dropout regulator to add an extra volt of headroom, that's not out of the question.

Comment: Give some consideration to the possibility of the resistor chain going open circuit and allowing the XORH voltage exceeding Vcc + 0.3 V which is an absolute max, I think.

Answer (score 4):

> using only passive resistance values?

I vote for the R-2R ladder approach.

The rungs of an R-2R ladder that are switched between two low-impedance voltages are the 2R components.  I like the idea of an R-2R ladder with SPST switches pulling one direction and low-value resistors pulling the other.  The problem is that the pull-down (for this discussion) resistors add to the 2R value in one logic polarity only.  That is, they add to the 2R value in the down state, but not in the up state.  This can be minimized by using low-value pull-down resistors but that increases circuit current, which could be a thing in a portable application.

The good news is that you already are driven to very high resistor values by the LT component.  With 1% values of 499 K and 1 M, a 1 K pull-down resistor adds a 0.1% error to the rung impedance, way less than the percent voltage change per address value.  The entire circuit requires 12 resistors, which can be implemented as three, 4-resistor networks: 3 - 499 K, 3 - 1.00 M, and 3 - 1.00 K.  As above, a larger pull-down resistor decreases circuit current but increases the step value error.  Life is choice.

The switch resistors can be either pull-up or pull-down, but I prefer pull-down.  In this way, turning a switch on increases the output voltage, a more natural way of thinking.

Here is a high-resistance integrated network at Digi-Key.  There might be others built for a 4-bit circuit that would be smaller.  This is not a complete solution; the circuit still needs the pull-down resistors.  But it does save space and reduces routing complexity.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/4816P-R2R-474LF/4697551?s=N4IgjCBcodIMZQGYEMA2BnApgGhAeygG0QAmUgZgA4B2ANhAF08AHAFyhAGU2AnASwB2AcxABfPAE4ooRJFSZcBYiAqTSYUgAYmrDpG58hosaaA

Comment: Yup, basically creating a D/A converter.  One advantage is a unique output for every possible combo of closed switches.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the outputs shown in the chart in the datasheet you can use the voltage divider and current source method as shown in another answer, but you need to use 5 resistors for the lower 4 bits and 4 resistors for the upper 3 bits.

For the lower 4 bits it would look something like this:
[image]

The current source would be set to \$V_{CC}\times 31.25~uA\$

Example, with a \$V_{CC}\$ of 5 V the current would be 156.25 uA and with the switches all closed the \$V_{XORL}\$would be
$$
156.25~uA\times 1k = 0.15625~V
$$
and \$V_{XORL}/V_{CC}\$ would be 0.03125 as shown in the datasheet chart.

Opening the switches would make that position a logic 1, with the 16k resistor being the high bit. For the upper 3 bits you'd use the same arrangement but leave out the 16k resistor.

If you have trouble getting a current source accurate enough at the nA level you could divide the resistor values by 10 or 100 and multiply the current by the same.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but is perhaps an alternative worth considering.

- Instead of DIP switches, it uses a 2x11 header, with a shorting jumper installed in one of 16 positions (some horizontal, some vertical).
- It needs 13 equal resistors (100K, perhaps), plus two resistors of 1.5x that value.  (The 1.5x resistors could be replaced by a series/parallel combination of 1x resistors, so you could do this with 19 identical parts.)
- You will presumably need two of these, to set both XORH and XORL.  Note that you can use the same resistor ladder for both!

[image]

(I had hoped to be able to provide a solution using a 2x6 header - which has exactly 16 ways to plug a jumper into it.  In fact, I can do a linear resistance choice that way, from 0R to 15R in 1R increments, but I couldn't think of any simple way to turn that resistance into the necessary resistance ratio.)

Comment: Ah! A man after my own heart. How to arrange combinations of plugs, especially canonical ones using all the possible arrangements).

Comment: How would you do the linear resistance with the 2x6 header? You could turn that into a voltage by using a current source instead of a voltage source. And I want to see your solution for that!

Comment: @Hearth: It's an extended version of an idea I had some years ago, for building a decade resistance substitution box using a 2x4 header (exactly 10 jumper positions!) per decade.  Originally posted at https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/low-cost-programmable-decade-resistor-for-prototyping-convenience/msg274353/#msg274353 .  The "hexade"??? version should just continue the pattern for two more rows.

Comment: @Neil_UK, the images for my circuit are showing up for me.  If you're talking about the original design that started that thread - it was a 2x10 header, with 9 Rs down one side, and the other side all connected together.

Comment: @Hearth A simple way to do 0-15 in a 4x2 would be a binary set in series, with a pin pair across each resistor. The following resistors in series - 1,3,3,3,3,2, have the unique property that you can select the resistance by choosing the goes-in and goes-out nodes, no jumpers required. This is especially useful if these are 4mm sockets, choose your digit value just with the connecting banana plug leads.

Comment: @jasonharper I can see the images now, must have been finger trouble. What an elegant scheme! I spent a day or two trying to find an arrangement myself, but hadn't got as far as those crossover links. Did you invent it, or has it been published before? It also works for transformer taps, which was the motivation for my 132 idea. I'm not sure how one would search for either of those ideas to look for antecedents.

Comment: @Neil_UK, it's my original idea.  Basically, I saw the original 2x10 solution in that thread, decided that there HAD to be some more compact solution (that didn't have half the pins connected together), noticed that 2x4 had exactly the right number of jumper positions, and wrote a Python script to brute-force the necessary arrangement of resistors.

Comment: @jasonharper  Well done. It's relatively tame for explicit MBB switching. If the starting and final settings share a pin, then you get to choose whether you undershoot or overshoot the settings with a temporary lower or higher setting. If they don't share a pin, then the worst case undershoot is R/3, eg getting 3.667 when 4 and 5 are in at the same time (I used to be involved in the design switched RF attenuators in signal generators, and was all over unwanted big transients to the user's delicate and expensive equipment).

Comment: @jasonharper Shorting the position of the '9' jumper does not alter the accuracy of all the lower positions. That would allow the overshoot on removing a jumper to be limited to '9' in that decade, probably tame enough for the majority of applications. Curse you Jason, you have now got my brain whizzing.

Comment: @jasonharper As I said, my brain is now whizzing. I have come up with a different, and arguably, <i>slightly</i> improved version of your scheme. If the resistor string goes 2,1,2,1,2,1, still with your general arrangement with the cross-overs, then the shorting link positions are in a nicer arithmetic sequence, with an increment of 3 every time you move a step further away from the end positions. I'm assuming the '9' link is permanently shorted, which avoids an o/c resistance overshoot, and avoids the second crossover.

Comment: @jasonharper I've now written a python program to evaluate ALL possible combinations of 4 to 9 resistors that sum to 9, and can be shorted by a single jumper to yield all 9 resistance values. (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) being rather trivial, and the subject of that EEVblog thread. The only 4 resistor ones are (1,3,3,2) and (1,1,4,3). Your (1,1,1,2,2,2) and my slight modification of it (1,2,1,2,1,2) are far from being the only ones that work with 6 resistors, however they can both be jumpered elegantly as you've shown. The 5 component (1,2,2,2,2) is quite compact.

Answer (score 1):

I like Jason's answer. Note that an array of pins may well be smaller in board area than equivalent DIP switches. If the arrangement is relatively permanent, then you don't need to fit the pins, and can program with solder blobs between the pin pads. If the board has a likely default setting, then it can be manufactured with a small trace across the 'on' gaps, to be Dremelled or scalpelled out if reprogramming is needed.

Solution for 2 rows of 8 pins, with 4 shorting links, that go only between the rows (so simple to silk-screen the instructions on). This was inspired by the switching inside my 4-decade precision voltage divider box. All the jumpers must be connected, so there's no 'where to store the unused jumpers' issue.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Ybaj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You keep exactly 4 jumpers connected, and move a jumper between its H and L position, which 'moves' the corresponding resistor between the top and bottom of the potential divider.

Here's a solution for 2 rows 6 pins, or two 'stars' of 5 pins (as each set of switches shares a common connection), with two jumpers always used. It's basically a two quaternary digit DAC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frwjr6.png)</sup>

The Vpad resistors are to get the end voltages correct, I'm not sure I fully understand the tolerances for the 0000 and 1111 programming voltages.

The Rout_pad resistors are to equalise the output impedance of the outer two states with the inner two, so that when the DAC is loaded by the other one, there will be no digit-dependent interaction. These resistors are all equal.

Choose the R_MSD and R_LSD resistors so that one DAC has 16x the weight of the other.

And finally, 4 rows of 3 pins, or equivalently 2 rows of 6 pins, will provide 4 SPDT 'switches' to program the standard R2R DAC ladder configuration.